Is it viable to broadcast a signal and be detected within starsystem distance?
Is it viable to broadcast a radio/EM distress signal from a space vessel that can be detected within a star system?

Think of an unexpected distress signal i.e. the receiving apparatus
shouldn't necessarily be pointed at that origin of the signal to
receive it;

The signal should be able to carry a small message (for instance,
the relative location and motion vector). It is ok the signal is
required to be a burst of repetitions and to have a minimum duration
to increase the chance of it being detected;

It should be detected within a star-system, so I expect it to take
hours to propagate.

Is should be detected within a star-system, so I suppose it must be
potent enough to be detected yet not so potent it'll harm the
vessel's occupants. Maybe this toll should go on the receiver (i.e.
be extra sensitive and be computationally capable of filtering it
from other sources);

Ideally, occupants should be able to send more bursts if they decide
to;

Receiver design must consider signal location ain't expected, so it must be able to detect and receive a signal from any direction;

Triangulation should not be a problem: the signal would pack location and current speed vectors.


Is it feasible? What should be the minimum duration? What is the power involved and relevant technical details? Would it require any unavailable (as of today) tech?
Edit:
ok, I figured a situation: there is FTL. You get stranded in an uninhabited star-system. If you're far away from the inhabited bubble of star-systems, you're probably doomed. But if you're not too far from the bubble, considering ships jump always within a 10 AU radius around stars (never in interstellar space), it narrows things enough and you have a chance: have a "bonfire lit" for when ships pass by. You never know where they'll enter the system. Given the time frames involved, you have to anticipate their presence. Thus, you need a "constant" broadcast.

While the idea is feasible, the response depends on a huge ton of factors, including, but not limited to available delta-V, the number of ships in that star system, the origin of the ship in distress, actual tech level of either ship or base(s) and more. My answer is based on current tech, as well as others' answers as I can see, but specifying the base tech level for the story would help, at least to yourself to decide whether the ship's crew expect the response at all, or they just are to send a SOS and perish.

we comunicate with spaceships on the edge of our star system using radio, so yes. see voyager 2

@John We know where voyager is, we're looking at it, and we use a ridiculously powerful array of telescopes to do so.

Yes
First, you can arrange the frequency range to be used solely by distress signals, and arrange a set of omnidirectional listeners to detect the signal in that frequency range, to minimize unwanted interference from common broadcast. Next, while the signal emitter would also be an omnidirectional, you might feasibly arrange the situation on a distressed ship to allow a transmitting antenna to focus the signal at least into a single hemisphere, towards the star, both lowering the required power to be heard, and protecting the ship from the signal itself. In fact, ships on Earth have buoys designed to emit SOS and remain afloat without relying on the ship, your spaceships should be equipped with similar devices powered by say an RTG, so that they would have power to detach from a distressed ship, compensate its rotation, position itself between the ship and the star, align speeds with the ship, aim towards the star (then aim at a rescue base, if desired) and then transmit SOS with a small amount of data received from the ship (current course, local time, expected destination, flight number, problem code, etc - this can be compacted into 1 kB together with ECC) until deactivated.
Now, for the required signal power. Voyager 1's transmitter has "mere" 23W of signal power, and is heard from more than 150 AU away. Given that your "star system" range does not exceed 100AU (and usually the planets of interest are relatively lose to the star, give or take several AU), you don't need to broadcast your signals too far. With Voyager's antenna saying to have a 48 dBi gain, which translates into 10^4.8 or 63000x power (with 1/63000 area of full sphere), your omnidirectional or one-sided transmitter with 23W power would be heard from a 250 times less distance, or 0.8 AU, at the same power level as Voyager's, which is "barely hearable". If you employ a simpler antenna that can be directed and has a gain of ~20 dBi and aim it to the location of the nearest known (or just "known") SOS receiver, you can extend that distance tenfold, which would be 8 AU and quite viable to both travel in the first place, and be heard in the second place. Then, emitting a four times stronger signal would allow its detection from double the distance, although shortening the sending time by a factor of 4. An example proposed emergency buoy should be hearable in an omnidirectional mode from ~4 AU, expecting its RTG power of 4 kW, and ~40 AU if it succeeds to aim properly and use the directional antenna to send SOS.
Now for the reaction and signal time. With a payload of 1 kB, and current downlink speed of Voyager 1 of 160 bps, the signal's length should be longer than 50 seconds - it's a lot for an emergency, but since we're in SPAAACE, we don't care about length but care about being heard. I'd design several standard baud rates for SOS beacons, based on distance from the star measured by luminosity, or rather by the ship route's largest distance from rescue stations, and ensure that the ship captains would program their SOS beasons prior to leaving the docks according to their declared route and destination. This way the receivers could be more precisely filtering out random noise and better detect distress calls, if any,effectively making a SOS be heard from farther away. So, the minimum signal length is effectively dictated by whatever SOS protocols are running in your star system, and the distance between transmitter and receiver, the farther, the longer.
In total: Yes, the idea itself is feasible; your ship that falls into distress can send a SOS so that it'll be heard at the "base", that SOS can also have a payload, the minimum length of the SOS is determined by payload, distance and other predefined constants, but will be longer than 0.1s per AU^2, give or take an order of magnitude, with currently used receiver of Voyager 1's signal. Using a worse receiver would proportionately lower the maximum detection range, but if there would be a space base, they will likely have a receiver of similar capability because of enough space around themselves, and low amount of unexpected emission.

What about cranking the power way up and the duration way down? So only sending chirps every few seconds or minutes. They only need to encode the information needed to aim an receiver antenna at the sender, so more data can later be transferred with less power.

@LazyLizard in deep space and in emergency you are limited to whatever power supply you've left, which is likely to be an RTG in the beacon pod. RTGs are limited to single kWs total power; and in order to supply the antenna with more power you need fast power storage (supercapacitors etc), which make the system more complicated and more expensive. Next, if your base has a spinning antenna that only surveys the full sphere in tens of seconds, having your transmission last longer could help being heard, otherwise that "chirp" might not be heard due to timing, which you don't need.

The scenario is about FTL ships stranded in an unknown solar system. At that tech level having a chunky capacitor bank shouldn't really be a relevant issue.
For buffering 1kJ (1 sek @ 1kW) that would cost about 3000$ in supercaps that you can buy off the shelf as a private person today. Basically nothing in spaceflight-money.

@LazyLizard still, they've got FTL with less than stellar precision (10AU? quite a huge miss for scifi standards) and also no FTL-comm (or denied due to power reasons in case of distress). So simple(r) systems win, and again, if you transmit a 1MW signal over a second and it just went unheard, what's your gain? Instead you transmit 1kW over 1000 seconds and have about a thousandfold chances to be heard, but indeed for the cost of longer waiting. In short, doable if wanted, but less reliable detection wise.

I think you misunderstand the point. Its not about sending 1s vs 1000s, but sending 0.01s @ 100kW every second instead of continuously at 1kW.
The timeframe in which the signal can reach anyone is the same, also the energy needed, but the range should be much better.
This would be bad if the goal is data transfer, but here the primary point is beeing noticed, transfer rate is almost irrelevant. The data is only coordinates + type of emergency (eg. MAYDAY/PAN PAN/SECURITE)

@LazyLizard oh, yes I did then. This would add to visibility vs omnidirectional receiver, so why not. I have just outlined the principles, details can be developed within "whatever SOS protocols are running in your star system". Still, 0.01s is decently long for a computer-based transmission, so you might be able to raise the transmission rate to transmit all the data you desire (while it's in the limits set by SOS protocols), not just what's listed here.


Is it feasible?

Remaining strictly within every single one of your points precisely, yes, it is feasible but somewhat constraining given a) the distances involved and b) constraint of an isotropic antenna (i.e all directions) c) the size restrictions on a spacecraft.


What is the power involved

Given the criteria, the transmit power required depends on:

how much you want the receive power to be
the distance
the operating frequency.

Let us assume that the answer to 1) is "no less than 1 bar".
Given 2 and 3, we can make a matrix:
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+
| Freq / Dist | Sun-Earth    | Sun-Pluto   | Helioshere diam.|
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 3 kHz       | 0.28 W       | 706 W       | 11,311 W        |
| 10 kHz      | 3 W          | 7,854 W     | 125,673 W       |
| 100 MHz     | 314 MW       | 785 GW      | 12 TW           |
| 7 GHz       | 2 TW         | 4 PW        | 62 PW           |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+

So the answer is "it depends". How far do you need the signal to go? What frequency should it operate on? Now, we'd probably want at least 10kHz, or the antenna would be the size of a town. But maybe this is a very big spaceship.
So if we assume 10KHz, if you wanted to transmit from the Sun to Pluto, then 7.85kW. (That's about 2.5 kettles, unless you live in North America; it's 4 kettles due to the voltage difference). As this is an emergency transponder which can "pulse", this is entirely reasonable and safe.
NB. if you wanted a hand-held instrument say to just cover ships passing by, within the inner planets of a solar system, 3W might be sufficient. Maybe the two systems could compliment one another, the latter used by a ship's landing crew.


relevant technical details?

Assumptions
Receive Power (Pr)
In order to calculate what power we need to transmit, we need to provide a criteria to what power we desire to receive. This is necessary for criteria 1 and 6. Sure, we can detect Voyager 1, but only with an array of massive dishes across pointing precisely at this part of space; that's no good. So let us assume that we want the receiver to have at the very least 1 bar signal strength on their radio; that's -121dBm, or 7.94E-16 W of power.
PW = 10 ((PdBm - 30) / 10)
= 10(-121-30)/10)
= 10-15.1
Frequency (f)
Attenuation (how much a signal dies off over distance) is proportional to the frequency. The higher the frequency, the poorer the range. (That's why 5GHz WiFi has shorter range than 2.4GHz WiFi). So we can select a range of frequencies:

An ELF frequency of 3Hz. Strictly speaking it is a radio frequency, but would probably not be practicable due to the specialist supermassive antennas required.
A VLF frequency a 10kHz. These transmitters have been used on satellites so it's practicable.
A UHF frequency of 100MHz. This is the band what's used in your car for FM, and in planes (including the black box).
A 7GHz X-band frequency. This is what they use on Voyager, but it requires massive amounts of power.

Distance (d)
Attenuation occurs over distance. If there was no distance, our would-be-saviours would have no problems picking up our signal. However us being in space, this is a major factor. We're not very specific on this, so I've covered a variety:

150M km; the distance from Earth to our sun. Maybe our would-be saviours aren't all the way the opposite side of the solar system, they're "passing by" where we're stuck?
7.5B km; the distance from the Sun to Pluto. I presume these are more the kind of distances you were thinking of.
30B km; the diameter of our solar system's heliosphere.

Calculation
Transmit Power (Pt)
This is where we want to get. This is calculated from all the other figures using Frii's transmission formula.
Pr = Pt (Gt Gr λ²) / ((4π d)²)
Where:

Pr = received power (watts)
Pt = transmitted power (watts)
Gt = gain of the transmitting antenna
Gr = gain of the receiving antenna
λ = wavelength of the signal (metres)
d = distance between antennas (metres)



What should be the minimum duration?

We've maybe got hung up on the premise that we're broadcasting data. What we're describing is an Emergency Position-Indicating Radio Beacon (EPIRB). EPIRBs, or locators, don't ordinarily transmit data. There is no need to; search and rescue teams locate the source of the transmission, nothing else. Locators just "ping" once a second until they run out of power, which is usually around 30 days; the reasoning being that someone requiring rescue beyond this point has probably succumbed to thirst, drowning, hypothermia or trauma.
However to satisfy criteria 2 we shall assume that a small message such as location and direction is transmitted. Given this is an emergency beacon I wouldn't recommend we use a high-data rate digital signal, but the criteria is for a minimum duration.
Assumptions

Limitations of standard consumer electronics apply
A FM modulated VHF signal is used with a maximum data rate of ~64kbps
Our data comprises of 6 high-precision IEEE 754 floating point (64-bit) 3 dimensional vectors (location, direction)
No error detection and correction mechanism is employed (as the data will be retransmitted continuously this would be pointless)
No additional control data is transmitted, such as an End-of-Transmission indicator. We are asking for the absolute minimum.

Calculation

Total payload: 6 x 64 = 384 bits
Transmission time: 64,000 bits per second / 384 bits = 0.006s = 600μs (microseconds)

Note that, being an emergency beacon, if you wanted to transmit this data, whilst not the fastest mechanism, a safer option would be to simply speak the information and broadcast this. It could be pre-recorded by crew, or Text-To-Speech updated by a computer. This is the way we used to transmit information in MI6 in the UK and overseas using "numbers stations". It means basic broadcasts can be understood by field assets without the need for specialist equipment.


Would it require any unavailable (as of today) tech?

Should be fine. It would require careful design, but we use 1MW pulses[23] for the RADAR on AWACS.
Possibly if this system was implemented in actuality, a rotating wide-beam directional antenna may be considered rather than an isotropic antenna in order to reduce antenna size and power consumption required.

Communication with Voyager continues even though it's left our system so it's definitely practical to communicate complex information over such distances with acceptable loss.
Voyager continues to communicate because it can focus its signal in one very specific direction, requiring exponentially less power than an omni-directional broadcast. So your transmitter needs to have enough power to broadcast in all directions. Or it could save a bit on power by sweeping a beam periodically.
The other element is the listener - something needs to be able to receive the signal, and someone needs to be monitoring that. Ideally multiple things are receiving, so the origin of the signal can be triangulated - that tends to be much harder to do with just one receiver, unless it can receive the signal enough times that its own movement through space can afford the triangulation.
Presumably this signal uses a standardized protocol - specific frequencies and patterns. If so, then it should be fairly robust even at the minimum broadcast power needed to cross the system. Assuming the standard was designed with the system's noise sources in mind, it should require little or no filtering to receive clearly.
Line of sight is also a consideration - a vessel on the opposite side of Jupiter is unlikely to get any signal to Earth on its own. A satellite network deployed on planets throughout the system could compensate for this, relaying emergency signals between planets using much more efficient directional communication. This probably also solves the triangulation problem, and reduces the broadcast power as well because you only need to reach satellites at the nearest planet.

Of course it's viable. The problem is reception
Check out this wonderful image showing the approximate distance human RF transmissions have traveled in the Milky Way.
Please click on this image to see it full-size. Courtesy Popular Mechanics (of all places).
By the way, what that image is showing you is the approximately 200 light year bubble around the Earth that encompasses the extent of the broadcasts. It's not the square box you're looking at... it's the blue dot in the inset. That's the bubble. "Space is big," intoned Douglas Adams. "You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space."
It's important to understand that RF transmissions are just another kind of photon, just like visible light and microwaves. They don't diminish over distance (but they can be absorbed... hence sunburns). In space, distance isn't the problem.
However, as they travel, there are fewer and fewer "per square meter" to be received. This is also true for light. It takes a LOT of photons to be easily "seen" or detected at a great distance. So the further one is from the source, the more sensitive the receiver must be to clearly detect the signal.
There's also a "window of opportunity." If the distress signal is broadcast for one hour, then there is a one-hour window of opportunity at any point in space to receive it. Assuming detection isn't a problem, that signal would be "heard" on the other side of the galaxy. Yeah, 106,000 years later, but if you were listening at just the right hour, you'd hear the signal.
So there are the limits of your effort to receive the distress signal. It can be received anywhere in the solar system so long as...

The receiver can detect the weak signal (weakened by distance).
Whomever is listening is, indeed, listening at the right time to hear the signal. This is more important than you might think. A signal broadcast from Earth can be received on Mars 4–22 minutes later depending on the position of the two planets in their orbits (and assuming that position doesn't put the sun between them... absorption...). So even if the distress signal is broadcast for days, there's a minimum amount of time before it arrives at the listening post before it can be heard. And after those days and that delay, it can't be heard. Hopefully the broadcast is long enough to do a little triangulation, which might require the receiving ship to move... which takes time.


Normally SOS receivers are on constantly, and in space I expect them being more than that, say passively scanning the entire sky sphere once in several minutes. Thus if the signal is longer than that period, which is known for every ship that's using the SOS system (or even globally as a system-wide or empire-wide standard), it will be listened for. Actual hearing would require receiver capabilities and specific signal characteristics to filter it from the space noise, this is possible to negotiate prior to launch tho.

@Vesper That may be true here on Earth where transmission distances are incredibly limited, and it certainly makes sense that some authoritative agency would specify a broadcast on frequency X, modulation Y and encoding Z to always be an SOS, but it doesn't change the fact of anything I've said. A continuously broadcast SOS is easy to find. A brief SOS is not. And having a 360x360 antenna array on every ship capable of listening across the entire heliosphere (OP didn't specify spatial limits, so I set the worst case) is impractical. Antennae in space are not the same as antennae on Earth.

I'm speaking about having such an antenna at every base, not ship, although ships can also have antennae dedicated to listening for SOS signals. Say, if there are 10000 ships in flight in a star system, each equipped with one, the average distance of a SOS to reach the nearest ship would be about 0.5 AU, which is even easier to hear and react than expected. If there are just a few like here, it'll be easier to plain track each of them from the base, knowing their relative coordinates if they don't deviate from the route, eliminating the need to scan all the sky sphere.

This is a frame challenge:
Why omnidirectional? Focus your power where you know you'll be heard. Suppose you are in an emergency situation on a ship, broadcasting to 99.9% empty space is a waste and a hail-mary. Instead, fire your antenna at someone that's easy to target and you know is listening. Like a base on a planet.
It takes 4.5 hours from Pluto to earth for an EM signal. That is a 9 hour roundtrip time where you know you'll be heard. Let "Huston" relay your SOS to the nearest capable ship and organize the rescue.


Why omnidirectional? Because that's my briefing for it. >Focus your power where you know you'll be heard. You can't know where you'll be heard. That's a given.


@FernandoD'Andrea A "frame challenge" is exactly that. I am challenging your requirement for omnidirectional comms. If your ship is from that star system, then you definitely know where there are inhabited bases. If you have power to send a message, you have power to turn on whatever gizmo gives you your current location. Even if you are running dark, earth, in this case doesn't move much in a day or ten. Aim the signal sunward and you will have better luck of someone hearing.

@FernandoD'Andrea If your species is interstellar and you arrived at this star system with other ships, I guarantee that all ships would know exactly where the others are at all times for safety. Then you would point your message at their last known location +- their movement potential.

The situation is like: there is FTL. You get stranded in an uninhabited star-system. If you're far away from the inhabited bubble of star-systems, you're probably doomed. But if you're not too far from the bubble, considering ships jump always within a 10 AU radius around stars (never in interstellar space), it narrows things enough and you have a chance: have a "bonfire lit" for when ships pass by. You never know where they'll enter the system. Given the time frames involved, you have to anticipate their presence. Thus, you need a "constant" broadcast.

@FernandoD'Andrea The problem you will run into is procedure. This is an advanced civilization. Space travel is very dangerous. This means that any successful space faring civilization will have successful procedures. Like only exploring unknown star systems in pairs. Or always dropping a radio repeater around a standard orbit of the main star to avoid just such an occasion. If your only recourse is to broadcast omnidirectionally for an entire solar system, you are statistically dead.

This is really a lossy communications channel problem.  We can invoke the Shannon-Hartley theorem to make sense of it:
$$C=B\log_2(\frac S N)$$
In this equation, $S$ is your signal strength, $N$ is your noise (from other sources like the star), and $B$ is the bandwidth of your channel.  The resulting $C$ is the channel capacity in bits per second. (assumes white noise, but you could use a different form if that mattered)
Of course, your message is really twofold. One is that you want to get their attention, and one is that you want to transmit your small message.  These do not need to be sent using the same channel.  Here's what I would do.

Send one signal with an astonishingly low bitrate.  It really only needs to have 1 bit of data: Mayday.  Repeat that slowly, possibly over minutes or even hours.   This calls for a very low channel capacity, so it will be able to be received despite high noise.  It is possible to design a signal that can be correlated on the listener side, letting them know there's an issue.
The listener, now knowing there is an emergency, uses this low bandwidth signal to direct a high gain antenna towards the sender.  This could take a while, as the signal is faint, but it's a relatively montonic process.  Once the listener realizes there's something to listen to, they will be able to narrow it in.
Now that the listener is pointed in the right direction, the noise levels involved are lower.  That's the purpose of the high gain antenna.  Now, on a separate channel, transmit your message at a reasonable rate.

You might consider modulating the message signal on top of the Mayday signal, but that's probably a topic for a far more detailed system.
Many have pointed to Voyager as a case study.  At time of writing, Voyager is sending 160 bits per second.  The antenna on Voyager 2 is a 10 dBi parabolic antenna, and it is being received by 70m Deep Space Network antennae with another 35 dBi, so the combined channel is at 45 dBi.  dBi measures the difference between that antenna and an isotropic (aka omni) antenna, so this channel is basically 45dB less noisy than an omni would be.  dB is measured based on log base 10, while the above Shannon-Hartley equation uses log base 2, so this high gain setup has about 150 times the channel capacity  of your emergency beacon setup.  Voyager 2 transmits at 23W, which isn't an unreasonable amount of power.
What does that pile of numbers mean?  It means that if you were to send and receive messages with omni antennae rather than the high-gain antennas used, you could detect Voyager 2's signal if it were transmitting at roughly 1 bit per second.
Now these are some fine, high quality radios.  I wouldn't transmit the mayday at that rate, but if you sent it at a rate of once per minute, that would buy you a lot of margin to ensure the message gets through.  And that's at Voyager distances.  Good luck accomplishing a rescue there!
